# display actionbar tabs below a xml layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I have successfully implemented the action bar and actionbar tabs in my app's UI. But the actionbar tabs always comes right after the action bar. I need to display a page header's xml view right after the actionbar. Right now even with the placements in xml the actionbar tabs always appear right after the action bar. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can change the place of this widget. It's related to your ActionBar, so you cannot detach it. Maybe you need to create a custom Tab but I think it's as huge as useless.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't do it. My suggestion is that you could disable the actionbar tabs and use viewpager component. You can put the viewpager inside of xml layout and you can set up tabs into the viewpager. For each page/tab of the viewpager, you could insert a fragment.

In that way, you can distribute the views of your screen how do you prefer.

Anyway, the ActionBar will be in the top of your screen filling all the width of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

You can change the `abs__screen_action_bar.xml` in action-bar lib if you are using lib project for action bar and tabs.

you can change this xml layout according to your need.